# writing a "Hello Android" program

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am really new in the Android world. I would like to try to write a simple "Hello Android" program that runs on an Android simulator. I have tried to Google here and there for the last couple of days to find a simple article that will guide me step by step.

Are there that kind of simple articles on the net? URL?

- I am running Ubuntu 10.04
- I have downloaded the android SDK Tools 10 and many more packages.
- I have browsed the [android-beginners] list
- I have read the FAQ list

What next? Thank you for any clues / URLs.

PS (added):

Basically, I am confused because every time I follow a new page, it will start with something like "you need to do XYZZY first". Again, when I went to XYZZY page, it will have a yet another prerequisite. Anyway, I have no idea what "eclipse" is, but I am going to install it yet. OK, I will be back soon. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Isn't there a 'hello world' app as part of the samples in the SDK?  You've looked at the documentation provided in the SDK, and the Google Android SDK docs/help pages, right?

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering why [this](http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+hello+world) didn't help you, but since it seems to have failed for you, let me guide you to:

- [the official google android hello world](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html)
- [moar good articles / examples / tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have [installed the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html), the [**Hello, World tutorial**](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) should be just what you are looking for ;-)

It'll guide you, with the following steps :

- Creating a Virtual Device for your tests
- Creation a new Android Project, with Eclipse
- Creating a first UI ; and using an XML Layout
- And it'll end with a few words on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you move out of experimentation into actual development, then I'd recommend getting a real device as soon as possible - emulator performance is really bad.

Depending on your requirements, [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) may be useful (although it seems more targeted at deploying Android to desktops than development for phones)

You can buy developer versions of phones through Android Market, once you've registered a seller account. These are network unlocked (can be good for testing if a messaging problem is network weirdness of a bug), and allow you to install custom images (mostly useful if you want to get into platform development).